# Login in a website with a CRSF Protection

Tags: php, oop, pdo, authentication

**Introduction:** 
I'm making a project that is based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc). A **PDO PHP-OOP** Login/Register script with some certain functions, and one of it is CRSF Protection. The CRSF Protection in this project is making a random token, and verify it everytime when user login/register.

**Problem:**
So here's the catch, how do I **login/register** on this website from another website? Just like the [Facebook Developers - Login API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)?

**Clarify things up:**
My problem is like this: 
 (all of the sites aren't true but it is only for demonstration)

I'm in *pleaselogmein.com* and there's a field that you can enter your login information for **thisismyproject.com**, and it's gonna log you in.

or this example:
I'm in *stackme.com* and I'm making a login form for Facebook Authentication, and Facebook lets me to use their API to login to Facebook while using my own field in my own website.

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is used for cross-domain requests. 'Handshakes' are made on authentication, OP visits site A and authenticates themselves, then site B get's an authentication code which requests the data through an endpoint on site A. CRSF is when you force cookies onto domains via requests, that is **not** what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As briefly explained in the comments section, the methodology to use is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

[image: CORS]

---

This is the idea that we re-direct the request so it becomes an internal request and the server then allows the request.

Let's say **Site A** is the domain we're contacting to login, a request from **Site B** is not necessary to start with. Instead, we *redirect* the OP to **Site A**'s authentication portal. Once OP authenticates, **Site A** will redirect to **Site B** with an authentication code (usually as a `GET` request in the URI) like this:

```
www.sitea.com/someController/someAction?someUrl=www.siteb.com&scope=user.Profile
www.siteb.com/someController/someAction?someAuth=someCode
```

Notice that in the **Site A** redirect, we also include some `GET` requests in the URI that contain the scope of information we're requesting and furthermore, the site return URI which you can validate in **Site A**.

Once **Site B** receives an authentication, the handshake can be created. A cURL request can be sent to **Site A** containing the Authentication and a response about the user will be returned.

```
www.siteA.com/someController/someAction?someAuth=someCode
```

Which would return something similar to a JSON encoded response like this:

```
{username: 'someString',
 recentlyVisited: {
     someDate,
     someDate,
}email: 'someString'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I found a hard time learning CORS, is there a tutorial for this to help me with the login?

Comment: There is plenty, this is a [REST-full API](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) example. Look-up using oAuth 2.1

Comment: What if this happened: I have my a.com (the client) and it has a login form, the login form gonna send a request to b.com (the server), and checks if the credentials is correct. If the credentials is correct, give a JSON string to a.com includes the user information. Can I ping you up or can you give me a link of a **authentication** CORS Tutorial using PHP and JSON + AJAX?